# Bluetooth connection attempt gives "Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed"

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I'm a recent RPi user. 
Pi version - Pi 3, Model B 
Bluetooth speakers - Philiphs BT64R

I've tested the speakers with other devices and the bluetooth pairing works fine. I've also tested my Pi with other devices and the pairing works fine too. Bizarrely, I can't get my Pi connected to the speakers.

Here's the trace:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl -a
[NEW] Controller B8:27:EB:6E:90:94 raspberrypi [default]
[NEW] Device F0:24:75:F0:7B:8C XXX's iPhone
[NEW] Device FC:58:FA:DC:9F:12 PHILIPS BT64
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# info FC:58:FA:DC:9F:12
Device FC:58:FA:DC:9F:12
    Name: PHILIPS BT64
    Alias: PHILIPS BT64
    Class: 0x260404
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
[bluetooth]# pair FC:58:FA:DC:9F:12
Attempting to pair with FC:58:FA:DC:9F:12
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists
[bluetooth]# connect FC:58:FA:DC:9F:12
Attempting to connect to FC:58:FA:DC:9F:12
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:DC:9F:12 Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:DC:9F:12 Connected: no
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:DC:9F:12 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:DC:9F:12 Connected: no
[bluetooth]#
```

I am not using Blueman. I tried it and then I couldn't connect to any device via bluetooth so I decided to try without it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting to an audio device, this could be happening for various reasons:

- Pulseaudio is not running (use `pulseaudio --start`)
- The appropriate module is not installed (use `apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`)

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258074/error-when-trying-to-connect-to-bluetooth-speaker-org-bluez-error-failed for more info

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled bluez after having install bluealsa.
Then I saw the following messages:

```
dietpi:~> sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-12-06 14:20:41 CET; 7min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 767 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9353)
        CPU: 150ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─767 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 06 14:20:41 LB2000P bluetoothd[767]: Starting SDP server
Dec 06 14:20:41 LB2000P bluetoothd[767]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
Dec 06 14:20:41 LB2000P bluetoothd[767]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
Dec 06 14:20:41 LB2000P bluetoothd[767]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Dec 06 14:20:42 LB2000P bluetoothd[767]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.7 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/source/1
Dec 06 14:20:42 LB2000P bluetoothd[767]: Failed to set privacy: Rejected (0x0b)
Dec 06 14:20:42 LB2000P bluetoothd[767]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.7 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/source/2
Dec 06 14:20:42 LB2000P bluetoothd[767]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.7 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/sink/1
Dec 06 14:20:42 LB2000P bluetoothd[767]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.7 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/sink/2
Dec 06 14:25:12 LB2000P bluetoothd[767]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_4C_87_5D_7F_BF_2B/sep1/fd0: fd(35) ready
```

I belief this /org/bluez to be the key, don't let the bluealsa service register them first.

Answer (score -1):

you need install pulseaudio and enable each time it by 'pulseaudio -D', then you can connect your bt.